# Unable to run GPU performance and diagnostics in VS2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, gpu

I am using Visual Studio 2013 with patch 4.

When I am trying to run a "performance and diagnostics" test for GPU profiling, the launcher immediately fails with the following output:

```
Profiling of 'Graphics Frame Capture' started.
Graphics Frame Capture has exited.
Profiling of 'Graphics Frame Capture' stopped.
Diagnostics session failed to start.

Failed to enable system trace session.
```

Mind you I can run the built-in graphics debugger without a problem on the same project.

What gives?`

I am running Windows 7 professional if it matters.

Comment: I got the same thing, with the same version of VS; the only difference, seemingly, is that I'm using C#

Comment: @BClayShannon, have you tried using a launcher app to start your C# process ? It did help me in the same configuration.